# Possible to check for back to back NAs in a column and split data between those two NAs?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |

Within the dataset, one of the columns has an N/A every other row and sometimes back to back. What I would like to do is create new tables whenever there are two back to back N/As so that the above dataset will look like this such that its broken into multiple datasets:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | N/A | Three |

**Reproducible sample data**

```
structure(list(X1 = c("One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", 
"One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", 
"One", "One", "One", "One"), X2 = c("N/A", "Two", "N/A", "Two", 
"N/A", "N/A", "Two", "N/A", "Two", "N/A", "Two", "N/A", "Two", 
"N/A", "N/A", "Two", "N/A", "Two", "N/A"), X3 = c("Three", "Three", 
"Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", 
"Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", 
"Three", "Three", "Three")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Comment: Please post example data in a format that can be copied and pasted (e.g. as the output from ```dput()```).

Comment: @JWH2006 you mentioned you edited this question. I don't see any changes to your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr) 

df %>% 
  group_by(split_on = cumsum(is.na(X2) & is.na(lag(X2)))) %>% 
  group_split(.keep = F)
```

**Output**

This will output a list of length 3. Each element of the list is a `tibble`.

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  X1    X2    X3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 One   NA    Three
2 One   Two   Three
3 One   NA    Three
4 One   Two   Three
5 One   NA    Three

[[2]]
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  X1    X2    X3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 One   NA    Three
2 One   Two   Three
3 One   NA    Three
4 One   Two   Three
5 One   NA    Three
6 One   Two   Three
7 One   NA    Three
8 One   Two   Three
9 One   NA    Three

[[3]]
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  X1    X2    X3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 One   NA    Three
2 One   Two   Three
3 One   NA    Three
4 One   Two   Three
5 One   NA    Three
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c("One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", 
"One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", 
"One", "One", "One", "One"), X2 = c(NA, "Two", NA, "Two", NA, 
NA, "Two", NA, "Two", NA, "Two", NA, "Two", NA, NA, "Two", NA, 
"Two", NA), X3 = c("Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", 
"Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", 
"Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

Comment: Very Nice. I almost forgot about the `.keep` argument in `group_split`. It appears the `N/A` values are not actually `NA`s. They are just strings that act as `NA` values.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Yes, you're correct. They are character strings. I used what's posted in **Data** section of my answer which has them as actual `NA` values, assuming this is the form in which the OP has the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution. I first created a new grouping variable called `id` based on your preferred condition and the split the data by it.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(id = ifelse(X2 == "N/A" & lag(X2, default = "Zero") == "N/A", TRUE, FALSE),
         id = cumsum(id == TRUE)) %>%
  group_split(id, .keep = FALSE)


<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    X1: character
    X2: character
    X3: character
  >
>[3]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  X1    X2    X3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 One   N/A   Three
2 One   Two   Three
3 One   N/A   Three
4 One   Two   Three
5 One   N/A   Three

[[2]]
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  X1    X2    X3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 One   N/A   Three
2 One   Two   Three
3 One   N/A   Three
4 One   Two   Three
5 One   N/A   Three
6 One   Two   Three
7 One   N/A   Three
8 One   Two   Three
9 One   N/A   Three

[[3]]
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  X1    X2    X3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 One   N/A   Three
2 One   Two   Three
3 One   N/A   Three
4 One   Two   Three
5 One   N/A   Three
```