# Transposing a single row (top row) within a dataset to its own column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataset

```
df <- structure(list(
X1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
X2 = c("NA", "B", "C", "D"),
X3 = c("NA", "B", "C", "D"),
X4 = c("NA", "B", "C", "D")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I need to transpose the top row into its own column such that the data looks like

```
df <- structure(list(
X1 = c("A", "A", "A"), 
X2 = c("B", "C", "D"), 
X3 = c("B", "C", "D"), 
X4 = c("B", "C", "D")),  
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I have thought about just subsetting and taking the top row, then transposing only that one and then merging it back to the original dataset.

I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Edit, Thanks for everyone's help.

The next step is to take this and apply it to a list of tibbles that were split via group_split (code thanks to @LMc).

```
data %>% 
  group_by(split_on = cumsum(is.na(Company) & is.na(lag(Company)))) %>% 
  group_split(.keep = F) %>%
  `names<-`({.} %>% 
   map(~ .[1,1])%>% 
   unlist())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 "[<-"("["(df, -1, ), ,1,df[1,1])
```

:-)

Comment: equivalently: replace(df, 1, df[1,1])[-1,]

Answer (score 1):

```
df[,1] <- df[1,1]
df[-1,]

  X1 X2 X3 X4
2  A  B  B  B
3  A  C  C  C
4  A  D  D  D
```

Comment: Thanks for your help again. Is there a way to alter the tibles in the other line of code you provided? data2 <- 
data %>% 
  group_by(split_on = cumsum(is.na(Company) & is.na(lag(Company)))) %>% 
  group_split(.keep = F)

Comment: Alter it how? Please post on that question, if it's relevant to another post.

Comment: editted. Its from your help on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67643541/possible-to-check-for-back-to-back-nas-in-a-column-and-split-data-between-those?noredirect=1#comment119563534_67643541

Answer (score 0):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(X1 = first(X1)) %>%
    slice(-1)
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  A  B  B  B
#2  A  C  C  C
#3  A  D  D  D
```

---

Or in `base R` (`R 4.1.0`)

```
df |>
   transform(X1 = X1[1]) |>
   subset( seq_along(X1) > 1)
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#2  A  B  B  B
#3  A  C  C  C
#4  A  D  D  D
```